# php: suggestions to store massive array into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, multidimensional-array

What is the best practice to store massive multi-dimensional arrays into a mysql database? I am looking for an answer in terms of:

1. **Efficiency** - The results will be requested from the database frequently. Currently I am serializing & unserializing. I realize I may need to use `json_encode`/`json_decode` depending on application.
2. **Security** - I need to ensure that any data being passed will be able to `json_decode` or `unserialize` properly. I am currently having an issue with unserializing a huge array. It's returning an offset error. I understand that somewhere along the way when it was stored to the database, some data either became corrupt or there are characters somewhere throwing the error. How can I prevent this and/or ensure that **EVERY** store to the database is proper?

Comment: Can you give a short example of the data, and which bits are likely to change?

Comment: If data will be requested frequently, you can cache unserialized data in your application.

Comment: @Evaldas, The application might have hundreds or thousands of users. That would really stress the system.

Comment: @Jared, caching always depends form the situation. It is most useful when you have data which does not depend on the amount of users. But if your array will grow with each user then yes, array can be huge and putting it all to the cache is not a very good idea.

Comment: I ended up solving both issues (I think) by first serializing, then `base64_encode`ing then storing to db. This eliminates any special character issues (which is what was throwing errors in my unserialize process) and gives me data to easily retrieve without errors.

Comment: @JaredEitnier Ideally, they array should probably be stored in a native format in the database.  It might not matter for your application, but the way you're doing it now significantly inflates the size of the data, whereas storing it in a relational model could probably significantly reduce the size.